# How to display bootstrap carousel with 3 items per slide using Liquid Shopify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll, shopify, liquid

I am trying to create a bootstrap carousel that displays 3 items per slide using Liquid.
This is my sample code

```
  <div class="item active">
    {% for course in courses %}
      {% if forloop.index >= 1 and forloop.index <= 3 %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {% include "courses/box", course: course %}
        </div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    {% for course in courses %}
      {% if forloop.index >= 4 and forloop.index <= 6 %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {% include "courses/box", course: course %}
        </div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

At the moment, this code works but it is not dynamic. I would have to repeat the code for each loop and this becomes difficult when there are lot of courses/items that needs to be displayed.

I am wondering how I can somehow increment the forloop so it only displays 3 items/courses per slide. Kindly let me know if you need more information or code samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a better options but this is what I figured.

```
<div class="item active">
{% for course in courses %}
  {%- assign module = forloop.index | modulo: 3 -%}

  {%- if module == 1 -%}
    {%- unless forloop.first -%}
    <div class="item">
    {% endunless %}
  {%- endif -%}

    <div class="col-md-4">
      {% include "courses/box", course: course %}
    </div>

  {%- if module == 0 -%}
    {%- unless forloop.last -%}
      </div>
    {%- endunless -%}
  {%- endif -%}

{% endfor %}
</div>
```

To break it down.

1. I wrap the whole logic in the `<div class="item active">` and close it at the bottom.
2. I loop all of the courses
3. I assign a `module` variable which returns the module of 3 from the current `forloop.index`. So if you are on 3,6,9 etc.. index it will return 0.
4. I check if the module is 1 and if it's not the first loop ( this is because we already create the `<div class="item active">` and we don't need another one and the `if` will be true when you are on the 4th loop, 7th loop and so on, a.k.a the place we need to put a new `<div class="item">` )
5. I add the `<div class="col-md-4">{% include "courses/box", course: course %}</div>`
6. Finally I check if the module is equal to 0 or if this is the last loop ( because if it's the last loop we will have two `</div>` at the end ) and add the closing `<div>`.